# aws copilot-cli deploy using previously created manifest.yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-copilot, aws-copilot-cli

I initialized aws copilot application, so it created a copilot folder and inside that it created service details with `manifest.yml` file. And created my AWS infrastructure for me. After that I delete that infra using `copilot app delete`.

Now I want to deploy this without going to initialization process of copilot. How is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution which worked for me is:

You run `copilot app init` to initialize an application as you did previously. Then, run `copilot svc init`. When asked for the service's name, put the same name as you have before - this information can be found in `manifest's` `name` field.

Copilot will check if the `copilot/<service>/manifest.yml` already exists, and won't overwrite it if it has. As a result, your previous configurations in the `manifest` will stay.

Next time when you run `copilot svc deploy`, Copilot will deploy the service using configurations in the `manifest`. Since it's the same `manifest` as before, the configuration will be the the same.